# SQL Server 2016, cursor

Tags: sql-server

I would like to use a SQL Server cursor to jump through records of one table (`tblSummary`) and based on values from that table update column `EndValues` in a second table (`tblDetails`).

Desired result could be reached by below query but i need cursor:

```
SELECT d.id, d.subgroup, d.fraq, d.subaccount, EndValues = d.fraq*s.amount
FROM tblDetails d
LEFT JOIN tblSummary s ON d.ID = s.id 
                       AND LEFT(d.SubAccount,2) = s.mainAccount
```

I am attaching two .sql scripts, one prepares all necessary data (Data setup) and the other one with prefilled cursor (cursor.sql). Can any one update cursor in such a way that i could get the same result as above query?

--Data setup

```
--CREATE TABLES
CREATE TABLE tblSummary
(
    ID varchar(11),
    [MainAccount] varchar(12),
    [Amount] numeric (10, 3)
) 

CREATE TABLE tblDetails
(
    ID varchar(11),
    SubGroup varchar(30),
    Fraq numeric (10, 3),
    SubAccount int,
    EndValues numeric (10, 3) NULL
)

--POPULATE TABLES
INSERT INTO tblDetails (ID, SubGroup, Fraq, SubAccount, EndValues) 
VALUES
('Garden', 'Sub1', 0.2,101,NULL),
('Garden', 'Sub2', 0.5,102,NULL),
('Garden', 'Sub3', 0.3,103,NULL),
('Garden', 'Sub1', 0.1,201,NULL),
('Garden', 'Sub2', 0.5,202,NULL),
('Garden', 'Sub3', 0.9,203,NULL),
('Home', 'Sub1', 0.1,101,NULL),
('Home', 'Sub2', 0.3,102,NULL),
('Home', 'Sub3', 0.5,103,NULL),
('Home', 'Sub1', 0.8,201,NULL),
('Home', 'Sub2', 0.1,202,NULL),
('Home', 'Sub3', 0.1,203,NULL)



INSERT INTO tblSummary (ID, MainAccount, Amount) VALUES 
('Garden',10,1000),
('Garden',20,1200),
('Home',10,2000),
('Home',20,2500)


--DESIRED OUTPUT
SELECT d.id, d.subgroup, d.fraq, d.subaccount,EndValues=d.fraq*s.amount
FROM tblDetails d
LEFT JOIN tblSummary s 
ON d.ID=s.id and LEFT(d.SubAccount,2) = s.mainAccount
```

--CURSOR

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(11)
DECLARE @MainAccount  VARCHAR(11)
DECLARE @Amount numeric (10,3)


DECLARE My_cursor CURSOR 
FOR SELECT 
       ID
       ,MainAccount   
       ,Amount
FROM tblSummary

 
OPEN My_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM My_cursor INTO @ID, @MainAccount, @AMOUNT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--CODE TO ENTER
    FETCH NEXT FROM My_cursor INTO @ID, @MainAccount, @AMOUNT
END
 
CLOSE My_cursor
DEALLOCATE My_cursor
```

Comment: Explain why you think you **need** a cursor. Cursors are generally rare in well-written tsql - but they are often an artifact of someone that struggles with set-based coding.

Answer (score 1):

I fail so see why you need a cursor, no one hardly ever needs a cursor!

You want to update the `EndValues` column with the calculation from your `select` query?

You already have the answer right in front of you, so unless there's something I'm not understanding about your problem, you just do this

```
update d set
    d.EndValues=d.Fraq*s.Amount
from tblDetails d
left join tblSummary s 
on d.ID=s.ID and Left(d.SubAccount,2) = s.MainAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I really get you problem, but you can just take your query as it is and declare a cursor for it

```
DECLARE my_second_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT d.id, d.subgroup, d.fraq, d.subaccount,EndValues=d.fraq*s.amount
  FROM tblDetails d
  LEFT JOIN tblSummary s 
  ON d.ID=s.id and LEFT(d.SubAccount,2) = s.mainAccount

FETCH NEXT FROM my_second_cursor into @id, @subgroup, @fraq, @subacount, @endvalues
```